# SyntaxError occurs when reading js.erb file with webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm currently developing with Rails5 and React.
And to use React, we use a gem called react-rails, and this gem uses webpacker.
At that time, in React, js.erb file was created to refer to the image precompiled with assets.
The information I looked up on the net had rails-erb-loader, so it should have been readable.
However, SyntaxError occurred.
I will write the details below.

- ErrorLog

```sh
# ./bin/webpack-dev-server
~~~
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /home/myproject/app/javascript/components/sample.js.erb: Unexpected token (1:1)

> 1 | <% helpers = ActionController::Base.helpers %>
```

- sample.js.erb

```
<% helpers = ActionController::Base.helpers %>

export const png_path = "<%= helpers.image_path('sample.png') %>"
```

- package.json

```
{
  "name": "Sample",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rails-erb-loader": "^5.5.2",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react_ujs": "^2.6.0",
    "reactjs-popup": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.2"
  }
}
```

How can I solve this error?
We will wait for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was not resolved. Sorry